# Error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the class 'Object'. - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having issues with getting messages fetched from Firebase Cloud Firestore. The error being displayed is: `'Error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the class 'Object' - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.'`

Below is my code:

```dart
class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: StreamBuilder<Object>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('chats/EKLJIb8ZfRoDTqxkkJaB/messages')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, chatSnapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: chatSnapshot.data.**docs**.length,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Text('this work'),
                  ),
                );
              }),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
body: StreamBuilder<Object>(
```

into this:

```
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
```

The `docs` is a property under the class `QuerySnapshot` and not class `Object`.

---

You have to specify the type that your `stream` returns. So if you have a `stream` of type `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`, then you add that type as an argument to the `StreamBuilder` as you have seen in the code above.

In the new `cloud_firestore` package, the `snapshots()` method returns `Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>` therefore you would do:

```dart
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
```

Adding `dynamic` might solve this issue, but it's preferable to add the type that is being returned because that way the editor or IDE will provide you with the code completion.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding the datatype as dynamic after StreamBuilder, in my case the answer "Peter Haddad" didn't work for me, I had the exact same error.

This is how I solved it:

```
StreamBuilder<dynamic>(....Your Code here....)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use dynamic, you should use the type that is getting returned in the `stream` in the above case it was `QuerySnapshot`